# Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, knex.js

I am having trouble with my migration to Ubuntu Linux.  I can use Postgres in the terminal. So I don't have a problem with the Postgres password.

When I type: `knex migrate:latest --env development`
I get: 
`Using environment: development
Knex:warning - Pool2 - Error: Pool was destroyed
Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user "user"`
I've read from other answers in related questions to go into the pg_hba.conf and set the method to trust. I've done this, but no change. 
my knex.js file looks like this:
`module.exports = { 
     devolopment: {client: 'pg',
     connection: 'postres://localhost/bikesdb'
     },
     production: {
     client: 'pg',
     connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
     }
   };`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to bikesdb with psql through TCP connection like this "psql -h localhost -U user -d bikesdb"? Are you sure you want to connect to db without password or would it be ok to create user for your database?

Answer (score 9):

You are most likely running on node `6.x.x` so you'd need to upgrade your pg package version `npm install --save pg@4.5.5`

Reference: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1371

Comment: I checked my package.json:  "pg": "^4.5.6".  Unfortunately, not as simple as that.

Comment: yes, this was it for me. upgraded to pg 4.5.6 and it solved my issue. thanks!

Comment: The same solution worked for me, with "pg" version 7.4.3

Answer (score 4):

If Andrei Stalbe's solution doesn't help... here are some more thoughts.

How are you connecting to postgres from commandline?

If you are writing just `psql bikesdb`it actually uses unix socket for connecting and it has different security settings in postgres by default than through TCP. You can try to change your connection string to: `postgres:///bikesdb` which makes also knex to use unix socket.

You can change/check security policies in `pg_hba.conf`.

Also you have typo in `postres://localhost/bikesdb`.

EDIT:

I'm pretty sure you are still having some general postgresql configuration problem. If you like to create user to access your database you can do this:

```
CREATE ROLE bikesuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'letmepass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "bikesdb" TO bikesuser;
```

And change connection string to:

`'postgres://bikesuser:letmepass@localhost/bikesdb'`

If you like to allow access from localhost to postgresdb this should do it in pg_hba.conf

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust`

Hope that something of this is useful, even that it sounds that you have already tried this all.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was just typing in psql bikesdb. I tried  changing the connection to``` connection: 'postgres:///bikesdb```. Sadlly nothing changed.  I temporarily replaced all my securities to trust just to get it working. Still nothing. I needed to reset the  passwords of user _and_  postgres.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and it was all about the fact that knex was trying to use the username taken from the environment variables (LOGNAME) of my command line interface.
If Postgres is set to use a different user (by default postgres if you haven't changed it) there will be an authentication error.
You can solve this problem by specifying the authentication credentials inside the URL that you use to connect to the Postgres server.

```
module.exports = { 
 devolopment: {client: 'pg',
 connection: 'postres://user:password@localhost/bikesdb'
 },
 production: {
 client: 'pg',
 connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
 }
```

};

I highlight the key point in the URL: 
postres://**user:password**@localhost/bikesdb

You can check the name of the user to access the Postgresql server from the UI interface provided by Postgresql and the password is the one that you have defined during the installation phase (if you haven't changed it)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently. My issue was I could run migrations on local macOS but not on a remote Linux Ubuntu machine. I found out that the reason was I didn’t have a password set for the user, though everything works fine on local for some reason it required a password on remote (Linux). So, setting password for the user and adding the password to the connection solved my problem.

Example:

On postgres

```
\password username
```

Then enter and confirm the password.

In your config file (e.g knexfile.js)

```
module.export  = { client: ‘postgresql`, user: username, password: secret }
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had a separate user for the psql db, and while the user itself had a password, the psql db didn't have a password set I guess. Using \password worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had set my psql to go to my user instead of postgres.  However, I reset the postgres password.  I just reset the postgres password, and the in the development connection I included the password. (I tried including it before the postgres password reset and it still didn't work). It's odd because the user I specified in the connection was me and not postgres.