# How to connect knex.js to PostgresSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Hi i'am trying to connect a database to server.js with Knex.js i have tried to add user as postgresql and i tried also to add host as localhost but that didn't work an i always get

Below is when i list all the databases!
[image]

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Below is a snapshot of my error when i tries to register me!

Below is my register.js that should help with the reigistering to the database!

[image]

```
    const handleRegister = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {
      const { email, name, password } = req.body;
      if (!email || !name || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json('incorrect form submission');
      }
      const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
        db.transaction(trx => {
          trx.insert({
            hash: hash,
            email: email
          })
          .into('login')
          .returning('email')
          .then(loginEmail => {
            return trx('users')
              .returning('*')
              .insert({
                email: loginEmail[0],
                name: name,
                joined: new Date()
              })
              .then(user => {
                res.json(user[0]);
              })
          })
          .then(trx.commit)
          .catch(trx.rollback)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to register'))
    }

module.exports = {
  handleRegister: handleRegister
};
```

Here is my server.js file below!

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');

const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');

const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'postgres',
    database : 'smartbrain1'
  }
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res)=> { res.send(db.users) })
app.post('/signin', signin.handleSignin(db, bcrypt))
app.post('/register', (req, res) => { register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt) })
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => { profile.handleProfileGet(req, res, db)})
app.put('/image', (req, res) => { image.handleImage(req, res, db)})
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => { image.handleApiCall(req, res)})

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})
```

And here is my databases that i have created in postgreSQL in the terminal as a snapshot!

[image]

Comment: I can add more information on Requests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by just trying to write standalone node app, that connects pg and runs a query. Then You can start integrating with other parts of your app when you know that connecting DB works as expected. Now the question has way too much irrelevant information.

First try to connect your SQL server from shell without using UNIX socket, but with TCP:

```
psql postgres://postgres@localhost/smartbrain1
```

If that fails, it probably means that your database is configured so that it does not allow any external TCP connections.

To allow access from localhost to postgres this should do it in pg_hba.conf by setting

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Also you may need to add password for your postgres user and try connecting with password enabled:

```
psql postgres://postgres:<password>@localhost/smartbrain1
```

When connecting from command line works you can try something like this in knex config:

```
const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 'postgres://postgres:<password>@localhost/smartbrain1'
});
```

Some more info for debugging this is found here [Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111578/knexerror-pool2-error-password-authentication-failed-for-user/38154476#38154476) and probably in tens of other generic postgres database connection problem questions.

Comment: Just changed the pga_hba.conf